# Attach and resizing div using jquery resizable handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to attach the handlers to resize `$('oWrapper_'+num)`. But it doesn't resize. I'm not if this issue is because the handlers are attached to the wrong div?

What I need is to be able to attach the handlers to `$('oWrapper_'+num)`and be able to resize using the handlers.

```
    num++
    var cloudWrap = $('<div />', { id: 'cloudWrap_'+num}),
        outerWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(cloudWrap)

        outerWrap.append(
            $('<div />', { class: 'tf', id: 'oWrapper_'+num, style: 'white-space:pre-line; font-size: 2vw;' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw hndl' }),
            $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw hndl' })
        );


        jQuery('#oWrapper_'+num).resizable({
          handles: {
            'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
            'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
            'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
            'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
          },
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        });
```

EDIT:

```
outerWrap.resizable({
              handles: {
                'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
                'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
                'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
                'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
              },
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          create: function(event, ui) {
                initDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
                initFontSize = parseInt($("#oWrapper_"+num).css("font-size"));
            },
            resize: function(e, ui) {
                var newDiagonal = getContentDiagonal();
                var ratio = newDiagonal / initDiagonal;

                $("#oWrapper_"+num).css("font-size", (initFontSize/100) + (ratio / (initFontSize/1000))  + "vw");
            }
        });

function getContentDiagonal() {
    var contentWidth = $("#oWrapper_"+CretCount).width();
    var contentHeight = $("#oWrapper_"+CretCount).height();
    return contentWidth * contentWidth + contentHeight * contentHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your id selector `jQuery('#oWrapper_'+num)`, when that is executed the new element is not yet added to the dom, so the selector won't return any element thus the `resizable` handler won't be initialized.

In your case the variable `cloudWrap` refers to the newly created element so you can use that to initialize the widget.

```
num++;
var cloudWrap = $('<div />', { id: 'cloudWrap_'+num}),
    outerWrap = $('<div />').appendTo(cloudWrap)

outerWrap.append(
    $('<div />', { class: 'tf', id: 'oWrapper_'+num, style: 'white-space:pre-line; font-size: 2vw;' }),
    $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne hndl' }),
    $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se hndl' }),
    $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw hndl' }),
    $('<div />', { class: 'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw hndl' })
);


cloudWrap.resizable({
    handles: {
        'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
        'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
        'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
        'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
    },
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Arun. Seems that's not the issue. The handlers attach perfectly. The only issue I have is that it's not resizing? I feel that the handlers are NOT attached to `#oWrapper_'+num` and I'm trying to resize `#oWrapper_'+num`. So it's not resizing?

Comment: @Fergoso can you edit the fiddle to recreate the issue you are having